# Check if the front end user is log in or not

Tags: plugins, login

I am using "front-end-only-users" plugin for user registration and log in system. Now how i check that my front end user is log in or not through coding i use 'is_user_logged_in()' but it checking the admin panel user.

Answer (score 2):

write this code in front page to check user is login or not:

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helful to you

```
global $current_user; // Use global
get_currentuserinfo(); // Make sure global is set, if not set it.
if ( user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) ) 
    echo 'User is a Subscriber';
else
    echo 'User is not a Subscriber';
```

Comment: how to check the user id.

Comment: by using this you can find the user id get_current_user_id( );

Comment: echo get_current_user_id(); give me 0 if user login or logout.

Comment: $user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
}

Answer (score 1):

The CheckLoginCookie() function will help you to get the current login username

you can get the username  by using bellow code

```
$UserCookie = CheckLoginCookie();
$username  = $UserCookie['Username'];
if($username){
  // User Login
}else{
   // User Not login
}
```